# nested accordion with jQuery-ui. Children closes their parents

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am having an issue when implementing a nested accordion. When opening a child, its parent closes instantly.

The solution I found was to declare a new accordion and a different header classes  for every level but since the nesting is unlimited it is not an option.

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     jQuery("ul.accordion").accordion({
         header: "h4",
         autoHeight: false,
         collapsible: true,
         active: false,
         heightStyle: "content"
     });
 });
```

I have created as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NahQ2/) to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
header: "> h4",
```

Cheers..